# Java EE 7 - Injection into Runnable/Callable object

Tags: java, concurrency, dependency-injection, java-ee-7

Concurrency Utilities(JSR 236) has been introduced in Java EE 7.

Is there any way how to inject my EJBs into Runnable/Callable object?

Specifically I want something like this:

ejb with business logic

```
@LocalBean
public class MyEjb {
    public void doSomeStuff() {
        ... do some stuff ...
    }
}
```

runnable/callable class where I want to inject instance of MyEjb

```
public class MyTask implements Runnable {
    @EJB
    MyEjb myEjb;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        ...
        myEjb.doSomeStuff();
        ...
    }
}
```

Object which starts the new task

```
@Singleton
@Startup
@LocalBean
public class MyTaskManager {
    @Resource
    ManagedExecutorService executor;

    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
        executor.submit(new MyTask());
    }
}
```

myEjb field in MyTask is always null. I suppose there could help JNDI lookup, but is there any proper way how to do this?

Comment: Googling around a bit, it seems that you should just be able to do it. Example: http://martinsdeveloperworld.wordpress.com/2014/02/25/using-java-ees-managedexecutorservice-to-asynchronously-execute-transactions/ . But as already said in another comment, you need to let the server handle the task creation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to give the container a chance to inject the EJB into your Task instance. You can do this by using a dynamic instance like in this code:

```
@Stateless
public class MyBean {
    @Resource
    ManagedExecutorService managedExecutorService;
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;
    @Inject
    Instance<MyTask> myTaskInstance;

    public void executeAsync() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        MyTask myTask = myTaskInstance.get();
        this.managedExecutorService.submit(myTask);
    }
}
```

Because you don't create the instance with the new operator but rather over CDI's instance mechanism, the container prepares each instance of MyTask when calling `myTaskInstance.get()`.

Comment: It is giving  "org.jboss.weld.exceptions.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: WELD-001308: Unable to resolve any beans for Type ..." Exception

Comment: @ravthiru - You need to make sure the bean you are passing in is managed by the container. E.g. Add "@ManagedBean" just before you declare the class.

Comment: I still get an UnsatisfiedResolutionException from my side

Comment: Could you please explain why this works: "@Inject Instance<MyTask> myTaskInstance;", but that does not: "@Inject MyTask myTaskInstance;"? Why do I need to use the Instance object?

Answer (score 2):

The EJB can not be injected if the MyTask instance is created by you because the Container knows only instances created by itself. Instead you can inject the EJB in the MyTaskManager Singleton SB and define your MyTask Runnable class as innerclass as follow:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
@LocalBean
public class MyTaskManager {
    @Resource
    ManagedExecutorService executor;

    @EJB
    MyEjb myEjb;

    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
        executor.submit(new MyTask());
    }

    class MyTask implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ...
            myEjb.doSomeStuff();
            ...
        }
    }
}
```