# Producer/consumer Pattern with dependency injection error

Tags: java, multithreading, dependency-injection, cdi, producer-consumer

[Java EE 7 - Injection into Runnable/Callable object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21078616/java-ee-7-injection-into-runnable-callable-object/52116266#52116266)

Continuing this question, i have a situation... I'm using a Producer/Consumer pattern to consuming a list of objects. My Class Consumer is a implementation of Runnable.

```
public class MYConsumer implements Runnable{

   @EJB
   private MYService myService;    

   private BlockingQueue<> queue;

   public MYConsumer (BlockingQueue<> q){
        this.queue=q;
   }
  @Override
    public void run() {
       /** Error is here**/    
       myService.insert(); 
    }
}
```

The implementation of the Pattern is working fine, but when i try to use myService, it is Null. The container not injecting the Service. I know it is because the Container knows only instances created by itself.

But how can overcome this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should instantiate your runnable object inside a session bean. This session bean will instantiate the service you want and then pass it to your runnable object.