# How to @Inject into a Runnable?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, ejb, cdi

I have this JAX-RS resource

```
@Stateless
@Path("")
public class ServerResource {

    @Inject
    ServerService service;

    @Resource
    ManagedExecutorService mes;

    @PUT
    @Path("/prepare")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void prepare(long id) {
        var info = new Info();
        info.setId(id);
        service.saveInitialInfo(info);
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/submit")
    public void submit(long id, @Suspended AsyncResponse response) {
        mes.execute(() ->  {
            var info = service.getInfo(id);
            if (info == null) {
                response.resume(new Exception("not found"));
            }
            info.doLongComputation();
            response.resume(info);
        });
    }
```

And this service

```
@Stateless
public class ServerService {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    public void saveInitialInfo(Info info) {
        entityManager.persist(info);
    }

    public Info getInfo(long id) {
        return entityManager.find(Info.class, id);
    }
}
```

`Info` is an `@Entity` with some fields (and an `@Id long id`) and `doLongComputation()` manipulates these fields and takes time.

The client calls `prepare` once. This creates an `Info` and persists it. Now the client will perform calls to `submit` multiple times (with the same `id`). The problem is that the changes to the entity done in `doLongComputation()` are not "saved". On the next `submit` call, the entity will be in the same state that it was persisted at at first.

Because `doLongComputation` takes a long time I am using an `AsyncResponse` and executing the method inside its new thread. The problem seems to be with doing the operations inside `mes.execute`. If I change the method to

```
    public void submit(long id, @Suspended AsyncResponse response) {
        var info = service.getInfo(id);
        if (info == null) {
            response.resume(new Exception("not found"));
        }
        info.doLongComputation();
        response.resume(info);
    }
```

then subsequent calls to `submit` will actually see the changes the previous calls did.

How can I @Inject into the asynchronous response method?

I am using JavaEE 8. Iv'e seen [Java EE 7 - Injection into Runnable/Callable object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21078616/java-ee-7-injection-into-runnable-callable-object) but that one is for JavaEE 7 and also the solution of using `@Inject Instance<ServerService> service` and then calling `service.get()` inside the Runnable does not help, probably because my classes are managed and there he creates one with `new`.

Comment: The problem is that the code executed in the thread is not part of any transaction. Instead of doing all that code there, do it in a method of another transactional (stateless) bean: `mes.execute(() ->  someOtherTransactionalBean.doSomething(id, response));`

Comment: @JBNizet If the code is not part of the transaction, why does `entityManager.persist` not throw an exception (specifically `TransactionRequiredException`)?

Comment: @JBNizet Also i don't understand why a `@Stateless` bean would solve this. The entity manager is already injected inside the `@Stateless` `ServerService` class, why is wrapping all that in another bean solve it?

Comment: I don't see any call to em.persist() in your code. Stateless makes sure that the code executed by the methods of the bean is executed inside a transaction. But the code is not executed by a method of the bean. It's executed in a separate thread. The transaction is bound to the current thread. Calling another bean inside that other thread will start a transaction bound to that other thread.

Comment: @JBNizet Your solution works. please write an answer so i can mark it as solved and give you the points you deserve